# Wrapper function triggering "Unknown variable references: [_MAPPING_VAR_0_0]."

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am currently applying a manual calibration on Landsat 8 images (manual because I want to simulate "noise" that could be introduced into the image--fed in as `ee.Lists`), and then compositing those altered images with `ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleCloudScore`. The idea is to slightly perturb each band's calibration gain, stored in the metadata of Landsat 8 images.

I am using several modules to do this (all linked below), and mapping the following function across the `ee.ImageCollection`:

1. a function that takes in the perturbation array (`ee.List`), returning a wrapped function that returns an `ee.Image`: `perturb.toa_Radiance(pert_row)`
2. the wrapped function in turn takes in an image, performs the manual calibration using the perturbation array (entered at the higher level in step 1)), followed by a cloud score and composite, then returns the composited image: `perturb.toa_radiance(raw)`

The relevant code snippets are below, with the links leading to the actual modules:

**Function 1**

```
exports.composite = function(collection,//img collection
                      asFloat,//do you want output to be reflectance units
                      percentile,//The percentile value to use when compositing each band.
                      cloudScoreRange,//pixels exceeding this will be rejected
                      maxDepth,
                      pertrow) {//pert_row would be the list by which you are perturbing the

  var pert_row = ee.List(pertrow);
  // Select a sufficient set of images, and comptute TOA and cloudScore.
  var prepared =
      ee.Algorithms.Landsat.pathRowLimit(collection, maxDepth, 4 * maxDepth)
                   **.map(perturb.toa_Radiance(pert_row))**
                   //.map(ee.Algorithms.Landsat.TOA)//This converts to Reflectance, change with your own function
                   .map(ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleCloudScore);//this should still work
  // Determine the per-pixel cloud score threshold.
  var cloudThreshold = prepared.reduce(ee.Reducer.min())
                               .select('cloud_min')
                               .add(cloudScoreRange);

  // Mask out pixels above the cloud score threshold, and update the mask of
  // the remaining pixels to be no higher than the cloud score mask.
  function updateMask(image) {
    var cloud = image.select('cloud');
    var cloudMask = cloud.mask().min(cloud.lte(cloudThreshold));
    // Drop the cloud band and QA bands.
    image = image.select('B[0-9].*');
    return image.mask(image.mask().min(cloudMask));
  }
  var masked = prepared.map(updateMask);
  print("just printing masked info", prepared);

  // Take the (mask-weighted) median (or other percentile)
  // of the good pixels.
  var result = masked.reduce(ee.Reducer.percentile([percentile]));

  // Force the mask up to 1 if it's non-zero, to hide L7 SLC artifacts
  result = result.mask(result.mask().gt(0));

  // Clean up the band names by removing the suffix that reduce() added.
  var badNames = result.bandNames();
  var goodNames = badNames.map(
          function(x) { return ee.String(x).replace('_[^_]*$', ''); });
  result = result.select(badNames, goodNames);

  if (!asFloat) {
    // Scale reflective bands by 255, and offset thermal bands by -100.
    // These lists are only correct for Landsat 8; different lists are
    // used for the other instruments.
    var scale = [ 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 1, 1 ];
    var offset = [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -100, -100 ];
    result = result.multiply(scale).add(offset).round().uint8();
  }
  return result;
};
```

**Function 2**

```
exports.toa_Radiance = function(pertrow){
  var pert_row = ee.List(pertrow);
  
  //usually it's a mistake to put such a humongous function inside another function
  //but we need the perturbation array to be a more global variable
  var toa_radiance = function(img){
    var image = ee.Image(img);
    //is wildcard supported (apparently, *)
    //this would probably be similar to the ndvi calculations
    //returns TOA value specific to band
    //var sun_ang = ee.Number(image.get('SUN_ELEVATION'));
    var d = ee.Number(image.get('EARTH_SUN_DISTANCE'));
    //var ESUN_list = [1876.61, 1970.03, 1848.9, 1571.3, 967.66, 245.73, 82.03, null,  361.72]; //CITE: Bunting 6S
    //var ESUN = ESUN_list[band_num.subtract(1)];-- only necessary if we are not using mult and add?
    //var sine_val = ee.Number(sun_ang.multiply(Math.PI).divide(180).sin());//radians
  
    //var constant = d.multiply(d).multiply(d).multiply(Math.PI).divide(sine_val);
    //now for the bands
    
    pert_row = ee.List(pertrow);
    print("input image", image);
    var extract_rad_gains = function(raw){//exports a list
      var b1_radmult = raw.get('RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_1');
      var b2_radmult = raw.get('RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_2');
      var b3_radmult = raw.get('RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_3');
      var b4_radmult = raw.get('RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_4');
      var b5_radmult = raw.get('RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_5');
      var b6_radmult = raw.get('RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_6');
      var b7_radmult = raw.get('RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_7');
      //var b8_radmult = raw.get('RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_8');//this be panchromatic
      var b9_radmult = raw.get('RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_9');
      print(b9_radmult, 'gain of b9');
      //List of MULT, excluding PAN
      var radmult_list =ee.List([b1_radmult, b2_radmult, b3_radmult, b4_radmult, b5_radmult, b6_radmult, b7_radmult, -9999, b9_radmult]);
      print(radmult_list, 'this is inside the extract rad gains func');
      return radmult_list;
      };
    var extract_rad_biases = function(raw){
      //ADD (bias) for RADIANCE
      var b1_radadd = raw.get('RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_1');
      var b2_radadd = raw.get('RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_2');
      var b3_radadd = raw.get('RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_3');
      var b4_radadd = raw.get('RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_4');
      var b5_radadd = raw.get('RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_5');
      var b6_radadd = raw.get('RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_6');
      var b7_radadd = raw.get('RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_7');
      //var b8_radadd = raw.get('RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_8');//this be panchromatic
      var b9_radadd = raw.get('RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_9');

      //List of MULT, excluding PAN
      var radadd_list =ee.List([b1_radadd, b2_radadd, b3_radadd, b4_radadd, b5_radadd, b6_radadd, b7_radadd, -9999, b9_radadd]);

      return radadd_list;
      };

    //cast as list
    var extracted_rad_gains = ee.List(extract_rad_gains(image));
    var extracted_rad_biases = ee.List(extract_rad_biases(image));
    
    print('REF MULT', extracted_rad_gains);

    var mult_list = perturb(extracted_rad_gains, pert_row);//should give perturbed info
    var add_list = perturb(extracted_rad_biases, pert_row);//should give perturbed info
  
    var band1 = image.select("B1");
    var band2 = image.select("B2");
    var band3 = image.select("B3");
    var band4 = image.select("B4");
    var band5 = image.select("B5");
    var band6 = image.select("B6");
    var band7 = image.select("B7");
    var band9 = image.select("B9");
  
    var band_list = ee.List([band1, band2, band3, band4, band5, band6, band7, band9]);
  
    //var toa_1 = (band1 * (mult_list.get(0))).add(add_list.get(0)).multiply(constant);
    var rad_1 = band1.multiply(ee.Number(mult_list.get(0))).add(ee.Number(add_list.get(0)));
    var rad_2 = band2.multiply(ee.Number(mult_list.get(1))).add(ee.Number(add_list.get(1)));
    var rad_3 = band3.multiply(ee.Number(mult_list.get(2))).add(ee.Number(add_list.get(2)));
    var rad_4 = band4.multiply(ee.Number(mult_list.get(3))).add(ee.Number(add_list.get(3)));      
    var rad_5 = band5.multiply(ee.Number(mult_list.get(4))).add(ee.Number(add_list.get(4)));
    var rad_6 = band6.multiply(ee.Number(mult_list.get(5))).add(ee.Number(add_list.get(5)));
    var rad_7 = band7.multiply(ee.Number(mult_list.get(6))).add(ee.Number(add_list.get(6)));
    var rad_9 = band9.multiply(ee.Number(mult_list.get(8))).add(ee.Number(add_list.get(8)));
  
    //print(constant, "constant");
  
    //print("this is rad_1", rad_1);

    var rad = ee.Image.cat([rad_1, rad_2, rad_3, rad_4, rad_5, rad_6, rad_7, rad_9]);
    return image.addBands(rad, null, true).toFloat()};

  return toa_radiance;//so this can apply to the image next
};
```

When I run the above mapped functions in the main script (https://code.earthengine.google.com/1515e322e19dbad45de2b26cb9605d6d), it throws a " `[_MAPPING_VAR_0_0].`", suggesting that this is a mixup between client-side and server-side. I know that there is something off about the wrapper function `toa.radiance(image)`, but casting everything as `ee` objects did not seem to resolve issue. Is it inherently not possible to map a wrapped function? Does it have to do with the fact that some of these functions are brought in via the `export` method?

**Modules:**

*perturb*: https://code.earthengine.google.com/1a3d804ad7f7f936cbe3fa54d67780bf

*compositing*: https://code.earthengine.google.com/4943b939b3d5533e26465dafcf163a3b

*classification*: https://code.earthengine.google.com/a81c7931bf5217fc47fa1823c7a4ba88

**Main script** (importing the above modules) : https://code.earthengine.google.com/1515e322e19dbad45de2b26cb9605d6d

Answer (score 1):

> suggesting that this is a mixup between client-side and server-side

Indeed. `perturb.toa_Radiance` contains several calls to `print()`. Since `print` is a function that itself sends a request to the EE servers, it cannot be used inside a `map()` — the mapped-over function parameter doesn't exist yet, which produces the error you see.

Comment: Indeed, getting rid of all the `print()` statements did the trick--perhaps some black boxes are not meant to be looked inside... Thank you again, Kevin